# Bootstrap 3 stack grid according to browser size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am designing a template for bootstrap

so far i have done [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c59nvodm/) and i am stuck with 2 things

I want to change the number of columns as browser window changes like following

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
 #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
 }
}
```

But if i use this code it gives very strange behavior, apart from that i also wants to change the size of font as window size changes.

So is there any other way to change the column size and font size?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a few minutes to understand the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system in bootstrap. The proper way to increase columns at various breakpoints is to add the correct bootstrap class for each size. The sizes are xs, sm, md, lg.

So the proper way to achieve what you need is to use the grid system:

```
3 columns for xs  - .col-xs-4                   because 12/4 = 3
4 columns for sm  - .col-sm-3                   because 12/3 = 3
5 columns for md+ - .col-md-offset-1 .col-md-2  because 10/2 = 5 and padding of 1 column

<div class="section col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2"></div>
```

For the font size you need to target the proper width like you were initially doing, but since we are using the bootstrap breakpoints we should also use them for the font. Looking at the link above we can see the media queries we need:

```
.section {font-size: 12px}    /* anything below 750 */

@media (min-width: 750px)  { .section {font-size: 14px} }

@media (min-width: 970px)  { .section {font-size: 16px} }

@media (min-width: 1170px) { .section {font-size: 18px} }
```

Comment: thank you mate. That solved my problem for grid but i am still stuck with font size,let me know if there are any other technique other than typography.

Comment: @BhavukSuthar Updated for fonts

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bootstrap, so you should take advantage of the CSS already built in.

Check out this example: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/bin/output.php

In this example he utilizes these classes: .col-sm-6 .col-md-4 .col-lg-3 to create a fluid layout.

Check out the documentation on the grid system and play with it to get the result you want. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: tank you mate but i solved the problem of grid with the same link, let me know if you any technique other than typography to change the font size

Comment: No problem man, this is a great tool for controlling typography http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/